Septic system's old and new pump tripping circuit breaker
Recently, a storm caused a power outage in my neighborhood, and immediately afterward, my septic system started malfunctioning. The circuit breaker in the septic control box began tripping whenever the pump tried to start.
I discovered that if I activate the "pump test" switch, which bypasses the circuit breaker, and then, after two seconds, turn on the circuit breaker before releasing the "pump test" switch, the pump completes its cycle and finished pumping effluent. However, the circuit breaker trips again when the pump tries to start on its own.
Initially, I suspected the pump's start capacitor was faulty. I measured the in-rush current at 62 Amps and an operational current at 10 Amps. I replaced the pump with a new one that closely matched the old one's specifications (w.r.t horsepowers and head), which reduced the in-rush current to 50 Amps and the operational current to 9.6 Amps. Despite this, the new pump still trips the circuit breaker.


If I understand the circuit breaker’s rating correctly on its sticker, then it should handle a short surge of up to 20 Amps. Now, I'm puzzled - how the system ever worked in the first place.

Could it be that:

I mistakenly have bought a new pump that isn’t optimized for startup amperage? But I really can't find ones that have 20Amps max in rush rating. The spec for my old 50f401e518c pump stated that it needs 20Amp circuit breaker, but back then I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that this 20 Amp circuit breaker rating was for operational amperage and not for in-rush. The new pump is WE20G05P4-21 and its spec clearly states that startup amperage is 64.4Amps@115V and operational amperage is 10Amps.
The circuit breaker is faulty? However, I swapped Singular Breaker with Pump Breaker (see picture of circuit breakers) and pump breaker still tripped.
After the surge one of the floats stopped to work, so I rewired it on Alarm float wires. Could this somehow could have provided extra amperage before?
I can simply upgrade circuit breaker that is rated for higher in-rush amperage?


I noticed that there were traces of melted wirenuts. So I got the IR camera:

After replacing wirenuts that were overheating, the in-rush amperage dropped from 50.7 to 43.5 amps. While operational voltage more or less stayed at the same 9.6 amps as before. The new 43.5 amps do not cause my circuit breakers to trip:

The lesson here is that bad(ly installed) wirenuts caused in-rush amperage to be by 20% higher than it should have been, while not having any noticeable impact on operational voltage at all.

Yeah, voltage drop issues generally compound themselves during motor start (lower voltage to the mower = more starting current = more voltage drop = yet lower voltage to the motor)
